# Application-wide repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a new webproject and I've encountered a problem which I never quite seems to figure out how to do correctly. My application is to use a repository that should be accessible from the entire application. Specifically it needs to be callable from ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters.

Any thoughts on the subject?

Comment: Have you tried adding "using MyApplicationRepositoryNamespace;"?

Comment: That sounds like one big violoation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are either looking for the [singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx) or an Dependency Injection container (like [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) or [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)) configured with a singleton lifetime for the object.

In a singleton, you put a static "Instance" property accessor on the object and have it always return the same instance. Two things to note on the singleton pattern though:

1. There are threading issues, which are covered by the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx) on singletons
2. It is generally considered an anti-pattern as it promoted class coupling

Using a DI container, objects are constructed automatically with any dependencies (constructor arguments). Objects configured with a "singleton lifetime" will only every be constructed once and the instance shared with all objects that depend on it (beware threading issues).

```
// The repository argument will be resolved by the DI container
public ObjectConstructor(IRepositoryInterface repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

In the case of Attributes (like ActionFilters), where the class is constructed by the runtime, you would access the container (or an abstraction of it) directly and request your instance:

```
this.repository = Container.Instance.Resolve<IRepositoryInterface>();
```